# Shell Script: while installing ncurses package using Cygwin64 Terminal on Windows, showing errors -E: command not found

Tags: shell, ncurses

While installing ncurses package using Cygwin64 Terminal on Windows, some errors are showing during the make process as follow:

Kindly note that i am using sed -x command at the beginning of current file named MKlib_gen.sh, one of the downloaded source files, to print out the commands and errors at the same time in order to help debug the code.

The 1st error:

```
    + preprocessor='gcc -DNCURSES_WATTR_MACROS -DNCURSES_INTERNALS -I../include'
    + AWK=-E
    + USE=-DHAVE_CONFIG_H
    ++ echo gcc
    ++ -E '{ sub(/^[        ]*/,""); sub(/[         ].*$/, ""); print; }'
    ./base/MKlib_gen.sh: line 87: -E: command not found
```

The 2nd error:

```
    + sed -n -f sed1_1576.sed
    + sed -e 's/NCURSES_EXPORT(\(.*\)) \(.*\) (\(.*\))/\1 \2(\3)/'
    + sed -f sed2_1576.sed
    + -E -f awk1_1576.awk using=-DHAVE_CONFIG_H
    ./base/MKlib_gen.sh: line 509: -E: command not found
    + sed -e 's/ [ ]*$//g' -e 's/^\([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_]*[ *]*\)/\1 gen_/' -e 's/gen_$//' -e 's/  / /g'
```

The 3rd error:

```
    + gcc -DNCURSES_WATTR_MACROS -DNCURSES_INTERNALS -I../include gen__1576.c
    + sed -e 's/  / /g' -e 's/^ //' -e s/_Bool/NCURSES_BOOL/g
    + -E -f awk2_1576.awk
    ./base/MKlib_gen.sh: line 521: -E: command not found
```

Kindly advise how to solve these errors.

Comment: cygwin has a precompiled ncurses package.  (It also has a package for gcc, which you appear to have not installed, giving the error).

Comment: Firstly, it's a great pleasure to receive reply from a reputable developer like you. Secondly and as per your kind reply, I have checked the gcc --version and found that gcc (GCC) 11.3.0 is installed on cygwin. Actually I am working on an android project and trying to create jniLibs architectures of ncurses to add to Android Studio, where I do not know the basics, and should be grateful if you could advise what is the right way to do so. @ThomasDickey

Comment: The error message suggests that there's something amiss with the scripting that sets the `CPP` variable (perhaps stray carriage returns = which I recall can happen with Cygwin if the disk mounts aren't using binary mode -- perhaps that's in an FAQ someplace).